# Transition array in parallel (Python 3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, indices

I am working on large arrays, and trying to compute the "transition" array (please tell me if that is the right word for it).
With a very simple example:

```
old_indices = [1, 2, 3, 0]
indices = [2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Since the element at index 0 (1) goes to 3, the first element of the transition is 3, the same for the element at index 1 (2) which goes to 0, so it would be 0, etc.
The transition should then be:

```
transition = [3, 0, 1, 2]
```

Then, a "transition map" can be created, which is basically the opposite way. The new element at index 0 (2) comes from index 1 in the old list, so the first element of the transition map would be 1, the element at index 1 (3) comes from index 2 in the older list, etc.

```
transition_map = [1,2,3,0]
```

I implemented something like this to create these lists:

```
transition = np.empty(indices.shape, int)
transition_map = np.empty(indices.shape, int)
for i in range(len(old_indices)):
    for j in range(len(indices)):
        if old_indices[i] == indices[j]:
            transition[i] = j
            transition_map[transition[i]] = i
```

Which works properly to create these lists. However, if I have hundreds of thousands or millions of elements in each indices list (of the same size), it starts to take more time.
I have 48 processors available for this calculation.
I was wondering if parallelizing this and populating the array could be beneficial. However, I have no experience in parallelization with Python 3. For instance, I do not know which tool I should use, and if the fact that I populate the same array with multiple processors would make it possible (or even, if the communication time would be too high to synchronize the array every time).

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a dictionary, which will make the whole process O(n). Give me a minute, and I'll write some mock code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fast : O(n)

Assuming that each element exists in both, this solution applies. To speed up the process, we can use a dictionary to keep track of the indices, where the key is the current value, which corresponds to the index. To make the naming easier to understand, I have called the variables `before` the transition, and `after`, so that we know how the transition maps it.

```
# Setup test cases
before = [1, 2, 3, 0]
after = [2, 3, 0, 1]

# Create the dictionary
for i, v in enumerate(after):
    indices[v] = i

# Find the indices for the transition array
transitions = [indices[x] for x in before]
```

To find your so-called `transition_map`, just reverse the names.

```
for i, v in enumerate(before):
    indices[v] = i

transition_map = [indices[x] for x in after]
```

Any questions or criticism, let me know in the comments.

Comment: It works well thank you! Is there any way of parallelizing that process? Moreover, would it be possible to get transition_map faster once we have the transition array?

Comment: They are both O(n) anyway - reversing one to get the other is the same time as just generating the reverse altogether.

Comment: @yvrob If it worked, please mark the answer as accepted, it would be very much appreciated.